# Wax between wheel centring and rim – is it necessary, and what wax to use?

Tags: vw, wheels, seat-cars, wax

Volkswagen Group tyre technical manuals (e.g. [this for the Seat Leon](http://www.seatia.com/secon-1391.html), [this for the VW Golf](http://www.vwgolf.org/wheel_change_protecting_wheel_centring_seat_against_corrosion-1991.html)) say that the "wheel centring seat should be waxed using wax spray to prevent corrosion between wheel centring seat and rim".

Is this actually necessary? I've not seen anything similar recommended for non-Volkswagen Group vehicles – everything I've found searching online is just talking about waxing the rim, not the centring – so I can't tell if this is just some quirk that everyone outside of VW dealerships ignores, or if it's genuinely a requirement for VWs for some reason.

If it is necessary, what sort of wax would be appropriate? The manuals just say "a wax spray", but that seems like it could cover a very wide variety of products!

Comment: You would use the same wax spray you would use to re-wax the engine after steam cleaning.

Answer (score 6):

While I'm sure there are other non-VW branded products that are similar, I believe they are referencing this product:

[VW Wax Spray](https://www.vwcarpart.com/oem-parts/volkswagen-wax-spray-d322100m2)

Comment: I guess they are suggesting a wax spray rather than grease because it is water resistant.

Comment: Grease, wax or what I use is anti sieze is a great recommendation. I live in the rust belt and many times have to take extra minutes to dislodge wheels.

Comment: @Jupiter FYI "the Rust Belt" has nothing to do with vehicle rust. It's the area of the US that was once heavily focused on manufacturing, but has seen factories shuttered as jobs have gone elsewhere.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that. I often use the term tongue in cheek to describe areas that use a lot of salt on the roads that heavily contribute to rust.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, have seen in the past many alloy and steel wheels that corrode and become very difficult to remove.

Even down to needing to use a large hammer to persuade the wheels to come off the hub.

Once removed, a thorough clean with a wire brush and some light grease, my favourite is copper slip, etc is sufficient to prevent it happening again. Does depend on the servicing interval as well...